# Data Hash attribute on Owl Carousel not working on dynamic generated carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, owl-carousel

Right now I am developing  the front end of a web application written in Jquery(JS). I am aiming to use Owl Carousel to load dynamic data from a JSON.

I already make it work to load all the items from the JSON and create the carousel dynamically on a "for" loop. Everything is working as expected, although my problem is to get de "data-hash" attribute on the url everytime I switch slider, I know that Owl Carousel has this function built-in on the plugin, but actually is not working on my code. Any Idea?

This is my code

```
    for (var key in data_allapprovedjson) {
    if (data_allapprovedjson.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        for (var key2 in data_allapprovedjson[key]) {
            console.log(data_allapprovedjson[key]);
            var itemid = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].itemid;
            var itemname = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].itemname;
            var itemdescription = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].description;
            var itemsellerid = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].sellerid;
            var itemsellername = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].sellername;
            var itemprice = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].price;
            var itemgender = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].gender;
            var itemfashion = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].fashion;
            var itemposeanimations = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].poseanimations;
            var itemhomegarden = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].homegarden;
            var itembodyshop = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].bodyshop;
            var itemmiscellaneous = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].miscellaneous;
            var itemmodify = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].modify;
            var itemcopy = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].copy;
            var itemtransfer = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].transfer;
            var itemexpire = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].expiresin;
            var itemimage1 = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].image1;
            var itemimage2 = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].image2;
            var itemimage3 = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].image3;
            var itemvideo = data_allapprovedjson[key][key2].video;
            //Variaveis Nome de elementos Estáticos no Layout
            var descricao = "Product Description";
            var variation = "Variation of this product";
            var permissao = "Permissions of this product";
            var linen = "$L ";
            var expiracao = "Expires in ";
            var sold = "Sold by: ";
            var vendorStore = "Vendor Store";
            var categories = "Categories";


            function init_carousel() {
                var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
                owl.owlCarousel({
                    items: 1,
                    loop: false,
                    center: true,
                    nav: true,
                    URLhashListener: true,
                    autoplayHoverPause: true,
                    startPosition: 'URLHash'
                });

                owl.owlCarousel();
                // Go to the next item
                $('#next').click(function() {
                    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
                })

                // Go to the previous item
                $('#prev').click(function() {
                    // With optional speed parameter
                    // Parameters has to be in square bracket '[]'
                    owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
                })
            }


            $('.owl-stage').append('<div id="" class="container-fluid min-vh-100 pb-5 padding-top-2 owl-item" data-hash="' + itemid + '"><div class="row"><div class="col-6 d-flex"><div id="carousel-thumb" class="carousel slide carousel-fade carousel-thumbnails" data-ride="carousel"><div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"><div class="carousel-item active"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(88).jpg" alt="First slide"></div><div class="carousel-item"><a id="lightbox" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(121).jpg"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(121).jpg" alt="Second slide"><i class="fas fa-search-plus zoom-icon"></i></a></div><div class="carousel-item"><a id="lightbox" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(31).jpg"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(31).jpg" alt="Third slide"><i class="fas fa-search-plus zoom-icon"></i></a></div><div class="carousel-item"><a id="lightbox" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(31).jpg"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(31).jpg" alt="Third slide"><i class="fas fa-search-plus zoom-icon"></i></a></div></div><a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a><h4 class="pt-3 title-variations">Product Images</h4><ol class="carousel-indicators"><li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/Carousel-thumbs/img%20(88).jpg" class="img-fluid"></li><li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="1"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/Carousel-thumbs/img%20(121).jpg" class="img-fluid"></li><li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="2"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/Carousel-thumbs/img%20(31).jpg" class="img-fluid"></li><li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="3"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/Carousel-thumbs/img%20(31).jpg" class="img-fluid"></li></ol></div></div><div class="col-6"><h1 class="product-title">' + itemname + '</h1><h1 class="product-price">' + linen + itemprice + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>' + expiracao + itemexpire + '</h1><ul class="vendor"><li><img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(121).jpg" style="object-fit:cover;border-radius: 100%;margin-top: 15px; margin-right: 10px;" height="40" width="40">vendorStore</li><li class="sold-by">' + sold + itemsellername + '</li></ul><div class="padding-top-30"></div><div class="padding-box"><h3 class="product-description-title pt-3">' + descricao + '</h3><p class="product-description-text">' + itemdescription + '</p><div class="padding-box"><form><div class="form-group"><label class="select-text" for="exampleFormControlSelect1">' + variation + '</label><select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1"><option></option><option></option><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></div></form></div><!--/Select Variation--><!--Product Category--><div class="padding-box"><h3 class="product-description-title">' + categories + '</h3><ul class="categories-list"><li>' + itemfashion + '</li><li>' + itemposeanimations + '</li><li>' + itemhomegarden + '</li><li>' + itemmiscellaneous + '</li><li>' + itembodyshop + '</li></ul></div><div class="padding-box"><h3 class="product-description-title">' + permissao + '</h3><ul class="permissions-list"><li><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>' + itemmodify + '</li><li><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i>' + itemtransfer + '</li><li><i class="far fa-copy"></i> ' + itemcopy + '</li></ul></div></div></div></div></div> ');
        }

    }
}


    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        init_carousel();

});
```

The Variable that is populating the "Data Hash" attribute is "itemid", but nothing is happening on the url, **when I inspect** the whole Owl Carousel, the value of that looped variable is printed on the "data-hash" as it should be but not sending it to the url when I drag or change slider via BTN like on this example: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/urlhashnav.html

I already tried the following:

```
 owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function() {
    window.location.hash = itemid;
});
```

- This Worked but it only returned the last value of the variable itemid on every slide.

Note: I am not an expert on JS but I understand the language and logic, but I am around this one for days and any help is welcomed. Thank you!